# Default a dynamic value in Combobox onload LWC

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am retrieving a set of values from apex through JS, I want to preselect the the first option in the Lightning-combobox **(the retrieved values are different for different users)**. I used @track variable and tried to set the value onLoad using connectedcallback. Below is the code snippet

HTML

```
<lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
            <lightning-combobox
           name="objPicklist"
           label="Objects"
           value={selectedObj}
           options={objects}
           onchange={displayObjRecords} >
        </lightning-combobox>
```

JS file

```
@track selectedObj;
objects = [];

connectedCallback(event) {
  
    optionList({
        userID : this.currentUser,
    })
    .then(result=>{
        var i;
        
        for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            const option = {
                label : result[i],
                value : result[i]
            };
            this.objects = [...this.objects, option];
            
        }
        //SETTING UP THE VALUE HERE.
        this.selectedObj = this.objects[0].value;
        
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        console.log('Error : '+ JSON.stringify(this.error));
    })
    
}
```

**I would like to default the first option retrieved in the lightning combobox.**  How can I do it in LWC?

Comment: Are you getting some error?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky Nope, The value is just not populating.

Comment: @PragadeeshDharshaV your implementation is correct and it should work, if it's not working then what I can assume is optionList() is not returning anything, try debugging it.
Also, do add a null and length check before accessing the first element of the response array

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version,

It seems to be working fine here:

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/enWpiQZZx8jl1OlicDeH

I made the object property reactive:

```
  @track objects = [];
```